# Make change stored procedure when scheduled job is still running

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, scheduler, jobs

I have a Job which runs at 12 midnight daily. The Job calls 3 procedures one after another.
Procedure1
Procedure2
Procedure3

Job execute

```
begin
    Procedure1();
    Procedure2();
    Procedure3();
END;
```

suppose at each procedure take 5 minute to execute.  What will happen if some one make changes to procedure 2 or 3 when the job is still running at procedure 1.

Does Oracle take a snapshot of all the called procedure before starting the Job or the changes will reflect?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: There is no snapshot.

Comment: I learned that, Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

After going forward without waiting for an Answer, this is what I learned.

There is no snapshot. Oracle call procedures as is at the time of the call.

Whatever changes made just before the call, is reflected even when the parent procedure is already running.

I made changes just before the Prent procedure call this Procedure in question and the change reflected.